# A question about Handlers in Android

Tags: android, handler

If I've got it right a handler works like a queue. So my simple question is if I first postDelayed and after that do I regular post. Will the second post run after the first delayed post?

```
handler.postDelayed(someMethod(), 10000);
handler.post(someOtherMethod());
```

Will the someOtherMethod() run after someMethod()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. The second one will be performed immediately when all pending handler requests (so on the UI thread) are done. The first will be appended after 10 seconds.

Hint: The handler takes a `Runnable`, so it looks like that:

```
handler.post(new Runnable {
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

**Update** based on comment:

The handler invokes the posted runnable on the thread on which `new Handler()` was called.

Comment: Will this happend in the UI thread even though im running it in a Service in a detached thread?

Answer (score 0):

No, 2nd post will run as soon as possible (before 1st).

Answer (score 0):

No, handler posts are asynchronous. what `handler.post()` does it that it adds the runnable to  the message queue. `handler.postDelayed()` adds the runnable to the message queue immediately , but the timer will be set to delayed ms , after which the runnable will be executed.

so all post does is , to add the runnable to the message queue.